# Big-O Notation and Asymptotics

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis, notation

Let

```
       d    
p(n) = Σ ai n^i 
      i=0
```

where ad > 0 is a degree-d polynomial in n, and let k be a constant. Use the definitions of the asymptotic notations to prove the following properties.

```
a) if k >= d, then p(n) = O(n^k)
```

There are also 4 more correspoding to the Omega, theta, small o and small omega properties but if I could get an idea on how to start I can figure the other ones out on my own.

Comment: You should post the question on this site (you'll probably get the best response(s) there): http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: -1: "Use the definitions of the asymptotic notations to prove the following properties". That sentence sort of kills your statement about this not being homework.

Comment: He could be revising for an exam...

Comment: I am doing just that actually, I was given sample problems from the book to help study from.  And I copied the question from the book.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple. Look at the Big O Notation formal definition here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_o_notation#Formal_definition, especially at the formula at the end of the section, `limsup`. What you're trying to prove is that the limit of p(n)/n^k as n goes to (positive) infinity is a real number. If k > d, the limit is zero. If k=d, then the limit is a_d. Why? Because it's a simple polynomial (of an order of d) over n^k, which is also a polynomial (of an order of k). Look at calculating limits of polynomials.

Comment: yea I know thats totally what I need however I dont know how to go about doing that generally, thats my issue, do you have any hints on that area of it?

Comment: what do you mean, generally? calculating limits is the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
a) if k >= d, then p(n) = O(n^k)
```

If this is true, then there exist N,  A and B such that:

```
p(n) <= A + B*n^k
```

for all n >= N

Such N,  A and B exist, take for instance:

```
     d    
 B = Σ ai n^i 
    i=0


 A = 1
 N = 1
```

You can leave it at that, if you think that's insightful enough, or actually proof by induction that this choice of N, A and B indeed makes the statement valid.

Comment: This really doesn't prove anything. See this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_example)

Comment: it misses a 'since everything was arbitrary, this holds'. It is no proof by example, since I did not choose a specific example, but an arbitrary example.